# Is there any advantage to researching all addons for a weapon type?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have the legendary gunsmith, who allows you to customise your weapons.

Once I started playing around with it, I realised that developing certain addons for one weapon would make them available to others in the same type - for instance, scopes & suppressors are shared between sniper and assault rifles, and certain ammo / magazines and stocks.

I realised that I was able to research the same addon (for example a foregrip) for two different assault rifles... so I was essentially paying twice for the same thing, since I can just customise rifle B to add rifle A's foregrip. However, not researching the foregrip for rifle B blocked further progress.

Considering that I'd end up researching the same thing more than once, it seems like a waste of GMP to research everything in a weapon type - is there an advantage to this, or would focussing on a single weapon (UN ARC for instance) be a more cost effective strategy?

Are there any addons for that weapon type that I would not be able to acquire if I chose a single weapon to develop?

Comment: Well, there's an achievement for developing 300 items, and you can only hold at most 5 million GMP, so it'd be a waste not to use them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, higher-upgraded weapons don't just come with more crud stuck to them. They also come with **more places to stick crud to them** (and some intrinsic boosts separate from their customizable parts). You can't put a foregrip on a gun unless the version of the gun you're customizing has an undermount slot, and as far as I can tell, everything with an undermount slot comes with a foregrip stuck to it by default.

That said, there are also things you'd want to put on a gun that are only available from other guns' upgrade trees. For example, if you want to stick a tier-2 suppressor on your Renov, you're not going to find it in the Renov's upgrade tree. You'll need to research a different weapon's upgrades to find one, like the M2000-D or the AM MRS-4.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that certain weapons have unique attachments. Some weapons also receive good attachments faster than others, or require lower R&D levels to get the good stuff. For instance, I think the AM MRS-4 is one of the fastest if not the fastest way to get the Medium durability rifle suppressor. You can also put a high-tech rangefinder on many different weapons, but the unlock is unique to grenade launchers.